# Moderator coverage

Tags: discussion, election

Moderator coverage seems somewhat patchy with for example North America being well covered but Europe less so.

Are there any UTC times that would benefit from more moderator availability ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of the active mods*:

3 Mods are in UTC-5, some tend to roll into work a bit later than others, but we're all most active in the 1300-2200Z range.

1 Mod in UTC+10, that mod get's up too damn early, so most active 2100-0600Z.

We're notably lacking in 0800-1400Z area, which is daytime for most in GMT, or UTC+1, or near there. The first of the UTC-5 mods to get on in the morning usually gets to handle a deluge of flags.

---

* Where "active" is defined as having handled at least 1% of flags in the last month.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for - thanks.

Comment: Heh, I might get up early but I do very little moderation past 1630+10 (or +11 as it is now).

Comment: 1% has got to be quite low activity. Does this mean that a full 50% of the current moderation team are less active than we would hope ?

Comment: @Iain Your powers of observation serve you well.

Answer (score 4):

With all currently active moderators except Mark living in the EST TZ (UTC-5), I think everywhere except the US could use more mod coverage. Europe is obviously lacking coverage  from morning till early afternoon.

Comment: Yes. I deal with a lot of EU-flags over breakfast.

Comment: I think this is the case but was looking for confirmation from people in the know.